# How to convert an Object of type byte[] to String

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors

I am having a function that receives an Object of type bytes[] which I need to convert as string. This is how my code looks like

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        byte b[] = "Hello".getBytes();
        convert(b);    
    }
    public static void convert(Object s){
        String str = new String(s);
        System.out.println("In method "+str);
    }
}
```

As suggested, I created a new String object by passing the bytes[] array as parameter. It is throwing the following error

```
TestClass.java:24: error: no suitable constructor found for String(Object) String str = new String(s);
```

According to my understanding, this is because at compile time convert() method knows "s" as an Object and not byte[].

But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Just change the method signature to `public static void convert(byte[] s)` ?

Comment: Consider a case where in the method is called by passing the parameter as Object[], will having the parameter as byte[] in method declaration work fine?

Comment: Javas compiler provides type-safety at compile-time, not runtime. So it will not check that the actual call to the method actually provides a `byte[]`, it will just see that you declared the variable `Object`, which does not match. For the compiler, it is not safe to assume that something declared `Object` is a `byte[]` and not a `Car[]` or a `Dog`. Learn how to do type safe programming, avoid `Object`.

Comment: byte is not even a class, it is a primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of two ways:

1. Typecast object into `byte[]` like `String str = new String((byte[])s);`

or

2. change the method signature as `public static void convert(byte[] s)`

Answer (score 1):

You know you're using a `byte[]`, so you could just declare that in the method's signature:

```
public static void convert(byte[] s) {
    // Here ---------------^
    String str = new String(s);
    System.out.println("In method "+str);
}
```

Comment: Will it work if I send the argument as Object of type byte[]?

Comment: Don't forget time goes faster the older you get. 20 years ago we already had C++98. Independence Day is older than that. This is what you'd have done 30 or 40 years ago. ;)